# Insert command is inserting duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that inserts a row into a database when a QR Code is scanned. It works great except it inserts TWO rows each time it processes. Everything is identical.

I have tried to get around it by getting a count of people by grouping by the DCheckIn field but it is grouping by date instead of date/time.

I would love to find out why it is inserting two rows each time. The code is pretty simple. And it only does it if it is scanned with a qr code reader on a phone.

The three numbers it gets are from the form on the previous page.

```
include('includes/db_login_articles.inc');
$id = $_GET['did'];
$THID = $_GET['id'];
$TID = $_GET['tid'];


$currenttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO Attendance (DCheckIn,Family,TNumber,Attendance) VALUES ('$currenttime', '$THID','$TID', '$id')";

    $insert_result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!($insert_result))
            {
                echo mysql_error();
                echo "<br>\n";
                echo "$sql<br>\n";
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, switch to PDO or mysqli. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: Are you calling this via AJAX perhaps? As-is, this code only inserts one row - meaning that how you are using this piece of code is making it run twice - I'd look into that, as its hard to say for us without additional details.

Comment: Yes, I am switching to sqli.. just haven't gotten to this page yet.  What do you mean the code using this piece of code is making it run twice? This is the only code on the page. It pulls the 3 variables and inserts

Comment: I'll switch it to mysqli quick and run it and see if that helps.

Comment: I doubt switching API will make any difference, but you should do that in any case for security reasons - also learn about [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) instead of running `mysqli_query()`, particularly when using variables in the query. But like I asked, is this code being run by AJAX, or are you accessing it directly?

Comment: Are you sure the page is only loaded once, maybe the QR reader redirects once?

Comment: No ajax. I have a page with a form where a ticket is scanned. It pulls the family number and ticket number from the ticket, the user clicks how many are in attendance and submits the form. This page pulls those three variables and inserts into the database. All using PHP

Comment: Here is the form that is processing: 
echo"<form  method=\"get\" action=\"Game_Check_in.php\"  id=\"searchform\">
 Number Attending Today:1
  <input type=\"radio\" name=\"did\" value=\"1\" />
2<input type=\"radio\" name=\"did\" value=\"2\" />
<input  type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$THID\"><input  type=\"hidden\" name=\"tid\" value=\"$TicketNumber\">
  <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/submit.jpg\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Submit\" name=\"submit\" />
</div> </form>

Comment: Is the PHP code above a minimal version, or the actual code? The indentations seem like other things might be happening.

Comment: The insert is the actual code. Nothing else on the page.. The page with the form  has more on it... too much to post in comments.

Comment: Do you have access to the servers access logs? The only way I could see this writing twice is with a second page load with the same form data. I'd suspect the time would differ in some instances there though.

Comment: Chris85, I can get any file I need. which one? The error log? Can we move into chat?

Comment: @KathyKaiserLees read your access log (/var/log/.../access.log) to check if the page are requested one or two times.

Comment: Sure, the chat option vanished for me, you wanna try it? You should be able to find the location of your access logs from the apache configuration.

Comment: Hey everyone, I am just going to start over in sqli and rewrite the page. I'll post an answer if I find it. I think it is just in the qr code readers pulling the page twice. thanks for the ideas.